# What version of Java supports GlassFish 7.0.0 on a Mac?

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans

I have NetBeans 17 and the highest GlassFish version is 7.0.0. I have Java JDK 19 installed but GlassFish tells me it is not compatible with JDK 19.

What version of JDK is suitable for GlassFish 7.0.0 or lower?

Comment: If you upgrade to GlassFish version 7.0.3 you can use any JDK release between 11 and 20: ["Eclipse GlassFish 7.0.3 compiles and runs with JDK 11 to JDK 20 releases."](https://glassfish.org/#:~:text=ASM%209.5%20integration.-,Eclipse%20GlassFish%207.0.,requires%20JDK%2017%20or%20higher.)

Comment: Please how do i upgrate to 7.0.3

Comment: Download links for recent versions: [download](https://glassfish.org/download_gf7.html). Download whatever recent version you want (why not just grab the latest?). Unzip the zip file, and then read the "README.txt" file.

Comment: I just posted an answer. See below. Actually the latest release is 7.0.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem. I just tried to start GlassFish 7 on NetBeans 17 using JDK 20, and NetBeans wouldn't let me do that. But when I selected JDK 17 instead it worked fine. So to resolve this:

- Use **Tools > Java Platforms... > Add Platform** to add *JDK 17* as a platform in NetBeans.
- [Download and install the latest release of GlassFish 7: version 7.0.4](https://glassfish.org/download).
- When you try to start GlassFish 7.0.4 as a server within NetBeans it will fail (*"GlassFish server could not be started..."*), but NetBeans should then invite you to select an alternative platform to use instead:

  [image: Select JDK]
- Note that if JDK 19 is your only platform in NetBeans you won't be given the option to select an alternative platform, and you won't be able to resolve the issue.
- Just select *JDK 17* as your **Java Platform** and click **OK** and everything should work. I am running GlassFish 7 on JDK 17 within NetBeans 17 which is using JDK 20 and it is working.  Using JDK 18 instead also worked for me.

See the [Eclipse GlassFish download page](https://glassfish.org/download) for details on the latest releases and their JDK requirements. It looks like all releases of GlassFish 7 formally support the use of JDK19.

Notes:

- Don't let NetBeans download GlassFish 7.0.0 for you; that is only going to lead to problems. Instead, create an empty directory (e.g. C:/GlassFish704), and then download and install the latest release, GlassFish 7.0.4, into that directory yourself. Then, when you add GlassFish 7 as a server, navigate to the root directory of that GlassFish 7.0.4 installation. In my case (on Windows) that path was **C:/GlassFish704/glassfish-7.0.4/glassfish7**
- Do not use GlassFish 7.0.0 because [there is an unrelated problem with the Admin Console](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/issues/23782): "GlassFish Server Administration Console (http://localhost:4848) cannot be loaded.". You will see a `ResolveError` in the GlassFish log, and you won't be able to open the Admin Console, typically from `http://localhost:4848/common/index.jsf`.
- I think a minor bug in NetBeans caused you to hit this issue, since NetBeans does officially support the use of JDK 19. It seems that there is a needless hard coded constraint preventing you from using JDK 19 with GlassFish 7.x.x.

Comment: Looks like am having issues with this on mac os

Comment: @SheriffSulemana OK. Please update your question to be more specific than _"having issues"_.

Comment: HI I am having an issue too with Netbeans 19, JDK 21 and Glassfish 7.0.9 `Could not find Java SE Development Kit to start GlassFish Server`

Comment: @qualebs I can reproduce your issue. However, the most recent GlassFish release that NetBeans 19 supports is 7.0.6. That works for me using NetBeans 19 and JDK 21. GlassFish 7.0.9 was only released two days ago, so you will probably have to wait for the next release of NetBeans to use it. Also, note that neither NetBeans 19 nor GlassFish 7.0.9 claim to formally support the use of JDK 21. You are using versions of three major products that have all been released in the past month, so it is hardly surprising that there may be compatibility issues.