# Cannot find required version of java tm runtime environment when trying to install Glassfish

Tags: java, netbeans, windows-installer, glassfish-3

I installed NetBeans and I installed jdk 20.

But when I try installing glassfish 3.2.2 I get the following error: "Could not find required version of java(TM) runtime environment in 'C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk-20'"

[See snapshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J22vh.png)

When I run java -version it seems like everything is installed correctly.

See snapshot of java -version result

I tried setting JAVA_HOME to the jdk path and adding %JAVA_HOME5\bin to PATH at the top of the list.

I also tried uninstalling a different version jre that was installed and uninstalling the sdk and reinstalling it.

Nothing of the above helped. What is the problem?

Comment: *and adding %JAVA_HOME5\bin to PATH at the top of the list.* But that wouldn't be quite right. You would **pre**pend  `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;`

Comment: I can't find Glassfish 3.2.2 on the [Oracle Downloads](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/ogs-v3122-downloads.html) page, nor on the [Eclipse page](https://glassfish.org/).  If you're using the Oracle one the last supported JDK was Java 1.7. I think you're trying to mix a prehistoric Glassfish with the newest Java and they are not compatible.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76222963/12567365) to a related question. It covers how to run GlassFish 7 using Java 17 and NetBeans 17.

Comment: *I think you're trying to mix a prehistoric Glassfish...* Hehe, yes. Considering version 4 came out in 2013

Comment: FYI, the current version of [Eclipse Glassfish](https://glassfish.org/) is 7.0.4. Supports Jakarta EE 10. Runs on (Java) JDK 11 to JDK 20.

Comment: @g00se The sentiment of your comment is completely valid, but just because version 4 came out in 2013, it doesn't automatically follow that version 3.2.2 preceded it. GlassFish 3.x support probably continued for several years after the release of GlassFish 4. The larger issue for the OP of course, is that the unsupported use of GlassFish 3.2.2 would probably also require using an unsupported JDK which would then mean that no supported version of NetBeans could be used either.

Comment: Just FYI, regarding your comments about `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` in your question, none of that configuration is relevant or necessary if you only intend to run GlassFish within NetBeans. But as others have already pointed out, your larger problem is that you are trying to use an old and unsupported version of GlassFish.

Comment: *it doesn't automatically follow that version 3.2.2 preceded it.* I see. Though that wouldn't be exactly brilliant version control

Comment: @g00se It's a common situation that an old release of major software is maintained long after a new one comes out, if only for fixes for critical bugs and security issues. A maintenance release of JDK 11 came out last month, and Oracle have committed to supporting Java 8 until 2030!

Comment: Yes granted but the point generally is that there would have to be special reasons to cling to such an ancient version. I suspect there are none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ensure that the JDK version you're using is compatible with GlassFish 3.2.2. You can consult the GlassFish documentation or system requirements for more information on compatible versions.

Comment: This answer helped me. [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76222165/what-version-of-java-supports-glassfish-7-0-0-on-a-mac/76222963#76222963)